# Как сделать счетчик уникальные просмотры на PHP?

Tags: php

Как сделать с помощью "ip" уникальные просмотры?

```
$id = $_GET["id"];
qeurycount = mysql_query("SELECT count FROM news WHERE news_id='$id'",$link);
$resultcount = mysql_fetch_array($qeurycount);

    $newcount = $resultcount["count"] + 1;

    $update = mysql_query ("UPDATE news SET count='$newcount' WHERE news_id='$id'",$link);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Здесь что-то не понятное, вам нужна уникальность по IP? Но где проверка IP вообще? Где запись, если этот IP пришел впервые?

```
  <?php
  $ip =  $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]; // узнали IP пользователя
  $query = mysql_query("SELECT `ip` from table where `ip` = '$ip'");
  mysql_fetch_array($query);
  if(isset($query['ip'])){
  exit;
  }else{
  // апдейтим кол-во уник просмотров
  }
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

При посещении страницы пользователем нужно записывать IP в отдельную таблицу, если в той таблице такой ip не был записан ранее

```
CREATE TABLE  `news_show` (
  `ip` varchar(32) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Количество всех просмотров

```
echo mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM news_show"),0);
```

Запись посетителя

```
$ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

        if(mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM news_show WHERE ip='$ip' LIMIT 1"),0)==0)
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO news_show (`ip`) values('$ip')");
```

Answer (score 2):

Ребята, вы так запросто вставляете `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];` в запрос, кто вам сказал, что там айпишник а не злобный sql inj? Кто мешает заголовок подменить?

По теме - ip не является показателем уникальности, есть целые города сидящие через один ip

При первом посещении, ставьте уникальный id в куки, или еще лучше в сессию, и по нему считайте. От чистки куков это в общем не спасет.

Comment: > Ребята, вы так запросто вставляете $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; в запрос, кто вам сказал, что там айпишник а не злобный sql inj? Кто мешает заголовок подменить?

Привет, паранойя. Айпишник берется из обратного адреса пришедших пакетов, где составить инъекцию просто не позволит длина поля, не говоря уж о том, что пакет с неправильным адресом будет сброшен еще на нижних уровнях сети. Айпишник НЕ фигурирует в заголовках.

Comment: @Etki, и всё таки, элементарный [iptolong()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ip2long.php) снимет приступ паранойи, а заодно поможет рациональней исходовать ресурсы СУБД, а так же упростит механизм обработки IP по маске

Comment: Никогда не наблюдали как в REMORE_ADDR попадает HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR?

Comment: @donkey нет

Comment: Нет, я согласен что это паранойя, но я реально видел хостинг, где работает именно так как описано строчкой выше.

Answer (score 1):

На таком уровне php вам нужен как просто посылатель одного запроса:

```
UPDATE news SET count = count + 1 WHERE news_id = :id
```

Я бы не рекомендовал, впрочем, реализовывать счетчики в той же таблице. Таблица новостей вряд ли обновляется так часто, как счетчики, это может помешать кэшированию на стороне БД, да и приложение становится менее устойчивым - с отвалившимися каунтерами выжить можно, новостями - нет.